# React native turn by turn navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps, react-native-mapbox-gl

we working with expo and using mapview, however, there are many restrictions in react native maps, as we are planning to implement turn by turn navigation. Integrating Mapbox would have been the best option, however we do not think it’s best to eject the project as expo doesn’t still support Mapbox. Although, I came across a package, react native maps navigation, I would like to know if anyone has been able to successfully implement it in their project and it functioned properly, and also know if there are any drawbacks that comes along with it. I am asking this because the author says “Please note that this module is usable but still under heavy development. Some properties and/or component names might change without notice.”
Kindly give your suggestions and advice. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Mapbox works very well in a react-native projects and recommend to use this service for your project but effectively, it don't works with expo so for me, you should eject your project to use it.

I paste here some packages I used for a GPS project (The last one is to get the current position of an user)

[react-native-mapbox-gl/maps](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps)

[mapbox-sdk](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js)

[react-native-geolocation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation)

Hope that could help you

Comment: how do you center the map like for example in google maps the recener button when you tap it it will center the marker and map on the center of the screen so user can see? and how do you animate the marker?